# Tutorial for Wt (c++ Web development)

Tags: c++, wt

Any tutorial for Wt (c++ wedevelopment)?

Is there any IDE for developing webapplication in WT, as in the case of qt such as Qt creator?

Can any one guide me for the installation of wt in ubuntu studio and compiling the program with a small example?

Comment: Hello. Why don't you visit the official website http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt ? It contains tutorials. Welcome into Wt by the way, it's a nice tool.

Comment: Rather a make-a-list question, isn't it?

Comment: Here is a tool that might help you:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wtdesigner/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [official website](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/) contains all the information you need.

Installation instructions for Ubuntu : http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/download or http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/projects/wt/wiki/Installing_Wt_on_Ubuntu

There is no development IDE specifically made for Wt. Treat WT as a standard C++ lib and use your traditionnal C++ IDE. I would recommend Eclipse CDT.

Exemples are shipped with Wt. There is a tutorial available : http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/wt.html

P.S. I find the tutorials quite poor. i'm thinking of writing one myself, but not now...

Answer (score 4):

Here are some Wt Articles that I found helpful as I was new to Wt too:
http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppArticle.htm

Also I recommend that you use the Wt forum and ask there when you start to develop your own application:
http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/projects/wt/boards

Answer (score 3):

I made some tuts for private teaching, you might find them useful, just builds a hello world app, bit by bit.

https://github.com/matiu2/witty-tutorial

To build them read the README file in lesson one:

https://github.com/matiu2/witty-tutorial/tree/master/lesson-00-hello-world-in-cpp

But the idea is you look at all the code, it's pretty short in lesson 00, and each lesson adds a little bit to the previous.